# Logstash Config File for IIS

Tags: windows, iis, logstash

I have recently installed the ELK stack on a Windows server (following this: https://community.ulyaoth.net/threads/how-to-install-logstash-on-a-windows-server-with-kibana-in-iis.17/)

I can get the IIS logs from the server into Logstash and into Elasticsearch, but I can't get the same logs from another server.

Here is my logstash config file from my second server;

```
    input { 
    file {
        type    => "IISLog"
        path    => "C:/inetpub/logs/LogFiles/W3SVC*/*.log"
        }
    }

filter {
    mutate {
        add_field   => [ "hostip", "%{host}" ]
        }
    dns {
        reverse => [ "host" ]
        action  => replace
        }
    }

output {
    elasticsearch {
        host    => "ELK01v"
        port    => "9301"
        }
    }
```

but there is nothing showing in Kibana

In the stderr.log for Logstash I can see the following;

```
Exception in thread ">output" org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$3.onTimeout(org/elasticsearch/action/support/master/TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:180)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(org/elasticsearch/cluster/service/InternalClusterService.java:492)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)
```

and this from the stdout.log;

```
{:timestamp=>"2014-08-22T15:04:55.775000+0100", :message=>"Using milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones", :level=>:warn}
{:timestamp=>"2014-08-22T15:04:55.853000+0100", :message=>"Using milestone 2 filter plugin 'dns'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones", :level=>:warn}
log4j, [2014-08-22T15:05:34.215]  WARN: org.elasticsearch.discovery: [logstash-WEB01v-3460-4038] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery
log4j, [2014-08-22T15:09:06.334]  WARN: org.elasticsearch.transport: [logstash-WEB01v-3460-4038] Transport response handler not found of id [240]
```

I've confirmed that I can telnet to ELK01v on port 9301, but I can't think what else could be causing these errors. Is there anyone with ELK knowledge that could help at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an indication that it's trying to join your cluster but wasn't able to for some reason (for example a firewall -- there is communication in both directions when it joins the cluster).  The easist solution is to add `protocol => http` to your `elasticsearch` ouput.  This will work since you've already verified the firewall is open in that direction.